# Spark: Load data partitioned by file structure

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have three logs, each of them stored separately according to `year, month, day, [hour]`. I would like to load them already partitioned according to date, and then join them on `uniqueId`. However, each uses different storage method:

```
var log1 = spark.read.parquet(s"webhdfs://log1/year=$y/month=$m/day=$d/hour=$h")
var log2 = spark.read.json(s"webhdfs://log2/$y/$m/$d/$h")
var log3 = spark.read.json(s"webhdfs://log3/$y$m$d")

val cols =  Seq("year", "month", "day", "uniqueId")
var logs = log1.join(log2, cols).join(log3, cols)
```

I know that spark is able to infer the partitioning based on the file structure by itself. However, it is not clear to me, how can I make spark infer that `log3/$y$m$d` should create columns `year, month, day` and partition the data accordingly automatically when the data is loaded.